# Crawling multiple levels in Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, multi-level

I'm new to scrapy and before I spend a superhuman amount of time looking through documentation and trial and errors, I thought I'd ask the experts if what I'm looking for is even possible.

1. Navigate to an application URL
2. From all the links on the site, filter a subset of links.
3. Visit each of these links
   3.1 For each link, scrape and extract and store some information
   3.2 There is a specific link in this response that I want to follow
   3.3 Scrape the response to this link and record that as well.

To achieve this, can all this be done in one spider or would i have to filter the links from step 2 and call a second spider for step 3?

Comment: I don't think you need _"superhuman amount of time looking through documentation"_. You may want to start with [`CrawlSpider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) which is used to follow links, that you can filter also. The example from the docs also extracts data in a callback. This is a good start for you to study (we can't do the study for you)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to go through the documentation and achieve this through a crawl spider. Now my next step is to login using scrapy into the website i'm scraping. I'm trying to login to amazon.com. but the robots.txt mentions that www.amazon.com/ap/signin is disallowed. I've set scrapy to honor robots.txt requests, as I should. Is there an alternate to achieve an authenticated session?

Answer (score 0):

Update : So this is definitely possible using scrapy. Atleast the multi level crawl is. I haven't gotten far enough to know if I can store and link items from different levels in the crawl so that I have the info at one place. But judging by the flexibility of scrapy i've seen until now, this might very well be possible.